# Parse.com error: invalid type for key '', expected array, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.8.3)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am using Parse framework in Swift. I have the following code

```
var user = PFUser()
user.username = "username"
user.password = "password"
user.addObject("firstname", forKeyedSubscript: "firstName")
user.addObject("lastName", forKeyedSubscript: "lastName")
user.addObject("mobileNumber", forKeyedSubscript: "mobile")
user.addObject("city", forKeyedSubscript: "city")

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
    if (succeeded) {
        //The registration was successful
    } else if let error = error {
        //Something bad has occurred
    }
}
```

In the web portal, it shows like this:

[image]

It creates 'Array's in the columns with the keys I have given. I want them to be strings. So, I have changed my code to the following. So, I have changed addObject to setObject as following:

```
var user = PFUser()
user.username = "username"
user.password = "password"
user.setObject("firstname", forKeyedSubscript: "firstName")
user.setObject("lastName", forKeyedSubscript: "lastName")
user.setObject("mobileNumber", forKeyedSubscript: "mobile")
user.setObject("city", forKeyedSubscript: "city")

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
    if (succeeded) {
        //The registration was successful
    } else if let error = error {
        //Something bad has occurred
    }
}
```

It shows the following error

```
[Error]: invalid type for key city, expected array, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.8.3)
```

How can I add strings in the columns with keys using Swift code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change column type for `city`, `firstName`, `lastName` and `mobile` to `String` on parse.com portal. You'll need to remove this columns and add new columns with same name and correct type.

Comment: No, it must be done on portal. You've created columns with incorrect data type on parse.com. You can work use them as arrays: `user["city"] = ["New York"]` but I'm pretty sure it's not what you want to achieve. Recreate columns on parse with correct type and you'll be fine.

Comment: Initially, I have not created any columns on the parse.com web portal. By running the above code, it created the columns with Arrays automatically. but, i want it to create columns with String using my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have already created columns on this entity that are of different type than you want to set now.

Basing on amount of data in your database I suggest you to remove those columns. You have to do this using the Parse dashboard.

Comment: I have not created any columns. I have run the above code and the columns are created automatically by the parse framework. Now, I want it to create the columns with Strings using code.

Comment: Yes you did. You don't have to create them on the website. Saving object with new property is enough to create a column. Another save with different object type for the same column will fail and only possibility to change type of a column is to remove it (on the website) and create again (on the website or in the app). You may also use new columns with new names. If you want to keep the data you have to do custom data migration probably by cloud code job.